# Notification.requestPermission() is not resolved

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications

In my web app I am using `const permissionStatus = await Notification.requestPermission()` to request permission for notifications. In some cases (until now only Android Chrome, but rarely) the dialog doesn't show up, and this promise is pending forever. Does anybody know why this happens? How can I prevent this?

Comment: do you have that line of code in a try/catch to handle promise rejection?

Comment: Yes I do. But there are no errors nor rejected promises, just a pending promise.